# Door Keycards with Command Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I am making a map based on the game SCP Containment Breach.
In the game you can find the following keycards:
 - level 1
 - level 2
 - level 3
 - level 4
 - level 5
 - omni card (opens all doors)

I would like to know if it is possible to make a door that you can open with these, but it has to be possible to open a level 2 door not only with a level 2 keycard but also with the ones with a higher level.

If it's not possible with command blocks, are there any mods for it then? Or maybe server plugins?

I hope someone can help me with this, if not I'll have to figure out something else.

(EDIT)

Already figured out how to do it with command blocks.

Comment: Could you explain how you want your keycards to work? Are the doors iron doors or made out of blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the idea to make an SCP:CB map before, and the way I did the keycards was the following. Firstly, the doors were iron. Your project doesn’t require command blocks as much as it requires redstone, more specifically item filters. Look up how to make an item filter, then hook a few up to the door. Let’s assume yellow concrete is Level 1 access, orange concrete is Level 2 access and red is Level 3 access. You want the door to be accessible to Level 2+. Have the player drop the item into a hopper next to the door, then have the item pass through the filters. Have it go through the one made for Level 5 cards, then the one for Level 4 cards, etc until you have the one for invalid cards. Make sure that each filter gives a comparator output when successful. You can then use that output to return the correct level keycard to the player and open the door. There is but one flaw with this system: if you put in an invalid card, no filter will pick it up and it will be discarded. There are two ways to fix this. Firstly, you could say the minimum keycard required for each door. Or, you could set up more filters that will catch and return the card to the player, but will not open the door.

Have fun programming the SCP’s, especially 173.

Edit: I know the “look up how to make an item filter” part is lazy, but honestly, the designs are pretty simple, but too complicated for this. Just make sure you hook them up to each other and that you have enough space to build them. In other words, **don’t do it on a superflat world at Y=4**.

Comment: Mhhh, I don't really like item filters, because they're so big... I really need something compact but if there's no other way I guess I'll have to use them.